# Change css in a second li for a known ul class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to highlight the ***second* li element** in a chosen select list with a ***known* ul class** "chosen-results".

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single select-or-other-select form-select required chosen-processed" title="" id="edit_title_field_und_select_chosen">
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results">
      <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">- Select -</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">select to create new title</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">This</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">That</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to always select the second li element inside the ul class "chosen-results" and change the css to highlight it?

I already tried many things including for now just to change the background via a simple `$("ul.chosen-results:second li").css('background-color','yellow');`

Ideally to have a different hover colour than the other li elements.

**UPDATE:** I also tried both below but somehow take no effect.

```
(function ($) {
   $("ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(2)").css('background-color','yellow');
 //$('ul.chosen-results > li:eq(1)').css('background','red');
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE 2** Full HTML BODY CHAIN

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node-add page-node-add-event-webinars i18n-en admin-menu coffee-processed masquerade-float-block-processed">
   <div id="site-content">
      <div class="row">
         <div id="second-sidebar" class="clearfix">
            <div class="flex-wrapper">
               <div id="content">
                  <div class="region region-content">
                     <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
                        <div class="content">
                           <form class="node-form node-event_webinars-form" action="/node/add/event-webinars" method="post" id="event-webinars-node-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                              <div>
                                 <div class="form-item-title form-wrapper" id="edit-title-field">
                                    <div class="form-item form-type-select-or-other form-item-title-field-und">
                                       <div class="select-or-other select-or-other-processed">
                                          <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-title-field-und-select">
                                             <select class="select-or-other-select form-select required chosen-processed" id="edit-title-field-und-select" name="title_field[und][select]" style="display: none;">
                                                <option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option>
                                                <option value="select_or_other">&lt; select to create new webinar title or choose from existing below &gt;</option>
                                             </select>
                                             <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single select-or-other-select form-select required chosen-processed" title="" id="edit_title_field_und_select_chosen" style="width: 446px;">
                                                <a class="chosen-single">
                                                   <span>- Select -</span>
                                                   <div><b></b></div>
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                                   <div class="chosen-search">
                                                      <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                                                   </div>
                                                   <ul class="chosen-results">
                                                      <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">- Select -</li>
                                                      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">select to create new title</li>
                                                      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">This</li>
                                                      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">That</li>
                                                   </ul>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                               
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why jQuery and not just CSS? `ul.chosen-results:nth-child(2):hover { background-color: yellow }`

Comment: nice one, thanks Andreas, didn't know nth-child works with css, I made that work by including the li element `ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(2)` ;)

I wanted to do it via JS so the .css will only be loaded on a page when actually used.

Comment: _" by including the li element"_ - Sorry, I guess I missed that somehow when writing the comment :/

Comment: much appreciated though, despite looking for JS i made this work temporarily and i learned some :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`:nth-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to select the second child element or [`li:nth-of-type(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to get the second `<li>` child element

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/). They're zero-based, so `1` would be the second element:

```js
$('ul.chosen-results > li:eq(1)').css('background','yellow')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single select-or-other-select form-select required chosen-processed" title="" id="edit_title_field_und_select_chosen">
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results">
      <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">- Select -</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">select to create new title</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">This</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">That</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried and updated my code above but it took no effect, can you check my function please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$("ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(2)").css('background-color','yellow');`

Edit :

I have tried it and it works fine check the following snippet

```js
$("ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(2)").css('background-color','yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single select-or-other-select form-select required chosen-processed" title="" id="edit_title_field_und_select_chosen">
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results">
      <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">- Select -</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">select to create new title</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">This</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">That</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, i tried and updated my code above but it took no effect, can you check my function please?

Comment: it works in the code snippet and I expected it too, i learned about :nth-child thanks! But in my page it's still not rendering it, I added the full BODY in my question, maybe it's having trouble locating it due to the nested flow?

Comment: I just tried your full body and it works fine as well , may be it related to Jquery version , what is your included version ?

Comment: thanks, I'm using 1.8 in drupal, trying to add this into  this js file that gets loaded https://github.com/CBIIT/nci-drupal-modules/blob/master/select_or_other/select_or_other.js

Comment: It works fine using jquery 1.8 , also adding this file not worked for me because Drupal is not defined , i was trying to help you but it seems to be a dependency issue.

Comment: Thanks, your probably can disable the Drupal specific functions. I even tried to simply add a separate standalone jQuery (see in my question)  as it should be possible to work despite Drupal.